# Ajax request returning 404 in Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.4

This is my script I am using in Laravel 5.4:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btnLogin").click(function()
                    {
                        // var username = $('#username').val();
                        // var password = $('#password').val();

                        // var form = new FormData($('.login-form')[0]);
                        var form = $('.login-form').serializeArray();

                        $.ajax({
                                    url: '/login',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'JSON',
                                    data: {form},
                                })
                        .done(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        })
                        .fail(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        })
                        .always(function(resp){
                            console.log(resp);
                        });
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

I have made a Login Controller In `app\http\Controllers\LoginController.php`.

Whenever an ajax request in console it is showing in `POST http://www.example.com/login 404 (Not Found)`

where `example.com` is virtual host created on wamp.

I am new to Laravel 5.4.